# asp.net website with service apis and azure deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, azure

I have a website with web services project. I deployed the project and its now failing. I suspect it's because all the service references urls are different in my local pc. I would prefer to have the deployment fix them. 64707 is the port for the services running from visual studio on my PC.

I could connect to the web service hosted in azure and rebuild the services in my project. I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Error i get in my azure web site.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:64707
```

Comment: web.config transforms should resolve your issue here. Assuming you are storing your paths in your web.config.

Comment: You are correct kyle. thanks. I am working on it now